# Electron App: How to pass data back to renderer after ipcRenderer.send()?

Tags: electron

I am trying to pass data back to the renderer after recieving a ipcRenderer.send() using ipcRenderer.on().

I have nodeIntegration set to false and contextIsolation set to true for security reasons.
I have tried ipcRenderer.on() in the renderer but that doesn't seem to be possible there, and any of the methods involving "require()" do not work with nodeIntegration set to false.

What can I use to pass the data?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **preload.js** file and [contextBridge](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge)

- For example  :

**in the preload file :**

```js
const {contextBridge, ipcRenderer} = require('electron');
    
contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('electron', {
    toMain:({args}, e) => {
        ipcRenderer.send(":toMain", {args});
    },
    fromMain: (callback) => {
        ipcRenderer.on(":fromMain", callback);
        return () => {
            ipcRenderer.removeListener(":fromMain", callback);
        };
    }
});
```

**- send data from main to render :**

```js
// main.js

mainWindow.webContents.send(":fromMain" , {args});
```

**Get data in render process:**

```js
// render.js

window.electron.fromMain((event , value)=> {
    console.log(value)
})
```

**send data from render to main :**

```js
// render.js

window.electron.toMain(data)
```

**Get data in main process :**

```js
// main.js

ipcMain.on(":toMain" , (event, value)=> {
    console.log(value)
})
```